# Printing a C++ struct

Tags: c++, formatting, c++20, boost

Critique?

```
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/pfr.hpp"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void print_struct(auto&& s) noexcept
{
  using S = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(s)>;

  [&]<auto ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
  {
    (
      [&]() noexcept
      {
        if constexpr(I && (I == boost::pfr::tuple_size_v<S> - 1))
        {
          std::cout << ", " << boost::pfr::get<I>(s) << ')';
        }
        else if constexpr(I)
        {
          std::cout << ", " << boost::pfr::get<I>(s);
        }
        else
        {
          std::cout << '(' << boost::pfr::get<I>(s);
        }
      }(),
      ...
    );
  }(std::make_index_sequence<boost::pfr::tuple_size_v<S>>());
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
  struct
  {
    int a;
    float b;
    std::string c;
  } s{1, 2.1, "wow"};

  print_struct(s);
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Here's [an example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IVPSNG5umQ3KRKCi).

Comment: Have you looked at [boost's example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr/tutorial.html#boost_pfr.tutorial.custom_printing_of_aggregates)? It just misses surrounding parenthesis...

Comment: @Jarod42 Nope, I meant this post to be a variant of the well-known printing-a-tuple problem.

Answer (score 6):

## It only works for some structs

Your `print_struct()` function only works for types that support aggregate initialization; it's not a perfect generic solution for printing the contents of structs. You might want to add a comment to explain that, and restrict the type of `s` using a concept so the compiler will be able to print a nice error message.

## Simplify

Your code is too complicated; you are handling the start, middle and end of a struct separately, when you only need to handle the first element and the rest separately. It also will not print empty structs correctly. Consider:

```
void print_struct(auto&& s) noexcept
{
  using S = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(s)>;
  
  std::cout << '(';

  [&]<auto ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
  {
    (
      [&]() noexcept
      {
        if constexpr(I)
        {
          std::cout << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << boost::pfr::get<I>(s);
      }(),
      ...
    );
  }(std::make_index_sequence<boost::pfr::tuple_size_v<S>>());

  std::cout << ')';
}
```

## Handle nested structs

If one of the members of `s` doesn't have an `operator<<()` overload for `std::ostream`, but it is a struct, you could call `print_struct()` recursively.

## Handle printing to other streams

Your `print_struct()` is hardcoded to print to `std::cout`, but what if you want to print to `std::cerr`, a file or a `std::stringstream`? You can easily support this by adding a reference to `std::ostream` as a parameter to `print_struct()`.

## Incorrect use of `noexcept`

Since you are printing arbitrary types, there is no guarantee whatsoever that your function won't ever throw, so you should remove `noexcept`.

## Ambiguous output

Simply letting the `std::ostream` formatter format values does not result in an output is guaranteed to be parsable correctly. Consider the following:

```
struct
{
  int a;
  float b;
  std::string c;
} s{1, 2, "3, 4); DROP TABLE Students;--"};

print_struct(s);
```

You might want to choose a serialization format that can be parsed properly, like [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Answer (score 1):

[Boost example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_pfr/tutorial.html#boost_pfr.tutorial.custom_printing_of_aggregates)  has already an example for printing aggregate. Format and naming are different, but to adjust to your style, it would be:

```
template <class T>
void print_struct(const T& x) {
     std::cout << "(";
    const char* sep = "";
    boost::pfr::for_each_field(x, [&](const auto& v) {
        std::cout << std::exchange(sep, ", ");
        std::cout << v;
    });
    std::cout << ")";
}
```

For your version

```
void print_struct(auto&& s) noexcept
{
  using S = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(s)>;
```

- `operator <<` might throw, so `noexcept` is suspicious.
- You dont actually use forwarding reference, const reference would be enough.
  and then the `using` would be unneeded.

->

```
template <typename S>
void print_struct(const S& s)
{
```

For

```
if constexpr(I && (I == boost::pfr::tuple_size_v<S> - 1))
{
  std::cout << ", " << boost::pfr::get<I>(s) << ')';
}
else if constexpr(I)
{
  std::cout << ", " << boost::pfr::get<I>(s);
}
else
{
  std::cout << '(' << boost::pfr::get<I>(s);
}
```

Your printing is buggy for several cases:

- empty struct print nothing (probably not expected)
- struct with one unique element( prints only `", xx)"`)

parenthesis should be print outside the fold expression
separator should be handled only for first or (exclusively) for last argument.

I prefer the `std::exchange` version of the separator over doing test on index, but I would say it is mostly just style.

Boost already provides way to iterate on each field (but without the index).

Comment: I think `if constexpr` is superior to `std::exchange()`, but anyway, whatever works. `using ̇ is not needed even in this example.

Comment: @user1095108: I consider both versions as similar and just *stylistic* difference. (I would bet that performance are similar and time would be taken by `std::cout <<`)

Comment: Consider that `boost::pfr::for_each_field()` will do something similar to your fold over an index sequence, the compiler will see that `sep` is assigned the same pointer in every iteration, so it can remove the redundant stores.